# Error in .ahp-file for R

Tags: r, rstudio, ahp

I'm developing new .ahp-file to solve ahp-problem using package AHP in R.

```
Version: 2.0
Alternatives: &alternatives
  Apteka 1:
    x1: 2
    x2: 5
    x3: 2
    x4: 5
    x5: 2
    x6: 5
    x7: 2
    x8: 5
    x9: 2
    x10: 5
  Apteka 2:
    x1: 2
    x2: 5
    x3: 2
    x4: 5
    x5: 2
    x6: 8
    x7: 2
    x8: 5
    x9: 2
    x10: 5
  Apteka 3:
    x1: 2
    x2: 5
    x3: 2
    x4: 5
    x5: 4
    x6: 8
    x7: 2 
    x8: 8
    x9: 2
    x10: 5
Goal:
  name: Choose Pharmacy
  preferences:
    pairwise:
      - [x2, x1, 0.964]
      - [x3, x1, 0.97]
      - [x3, x2, 1.02]
      - [x4, x1, 1.075]
      - [x4, x2, 1.13]
      - [x4, x3, 1.118]
      - [x5, x1, 1.008148]
      - [x5, x2, 1.058849]
      - [x5, x3, 1.049]
      - [x5, x4, 0.940833]
      - [x6, x1, 0.915278]
      - [x6, x2, 0.960159]
      - [x6, x3, 0.948558]
      - [x6, x4, 0.85537]
      - [x6, x5, 0.91213]
      - [x7, x1, 0.981111]
      - [x7, x2, 1.029365]
      - [x7, x3, 1.020437]
      - [x7, x4, 0.917315]
      - [x7, x5, 0.982963]
      - [x7, x6, 1.081415]
      - [x8, x1, 1.102222]
      - [x8, x2, 1.156455]
      - [x8, x3, 1.145516]
      - [x8, x4, 1.028889]
      - [x8, x5, 1.100741]
      - [x8, x6, 1.213558]
      - [x8, x7, 1.13172]
      - [x9, x1, 0.401944]
      - [x9, x2, 0.432434]
      - [x9, x3, 0.419788]
      - [x9, x4, 0.3825]
      - [x9, x5, 0.409167]
      - [x9, x6, 0.453373]
      - [x9, x7, 0.420437]
      - [x9, x8, 0.371111]
      - [x10, x1, 0.530556]
      - [x10, x2, 0.56205]
      - [x10, x3, 0.553757]
      - [x10, x4, 0.496574]
      - [x10, x5, 0.538889]
      - [x10, x6, 0.595503]
      - [x10, x7, 0.547381]
      - [x10, x8, 0.484444]
      - [x10, x9, 1.665794]
  children: *alternatives
```

But when using http://ipub.com/apps/ahp/ I  get

```
Error:attempt to apply non-function
```

When using RStudio I also obtain

```
Error in readChar(ahpFile, file.info(ahpFile)$size) : invalid 'nchars' argument
```

I follow the examples of .ahp-files in tutorial of ahp.

Comment: For what it is worth: it is not a YAML related issue. That document is valid YAML, so the errors come from interpreting the data structure loaded from YAML.

Comment: I entirely agree with @Anthon. It deals primarily with package AHP. But  "AHP" tag is not allowed in stackoverflow

Comment: That you cannot make tags yet is because of your [reputation level](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges), it is not that AHP as tag is not allowed. You need 1500 rep for that. I created the tag [tag:ahp] and submitted description/wiki for that review (I don't have enough rep to do that without others to review it).